# helm chart installation of cert-manager timed out for AKS

Tags: lets-encrypt, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I'm trying to create two kubernetes (AKS) clusters for test environment using Azure DevOps.  These clusters using letsencrypt certificates for their endpoints.  I'm therefore automating the creation of these certificates using helm charts.

For some reason, the cert-manager installation helm task times out if I create two clusters around the same time.

I have tested the same release process with a single cluster and there isn't a problem when i run my deployment.

The helm cert-manager installation command that runs is:

```
c:\agent\_work\_tool\helm\2.11.0\x64\windows-amd64\helm.exe install --set ingressShim.defaultIssuerName=letsencrypt-prod,ingressShim.defaultIssuerKind=ClusterIssuer,rbac.create=false,serviceAccount.create=false --name appl-cert-manager --wait stable/cert-manager
```

As i said, this command for the 1st cluster succeeds.  I receive a message:

```
16:20:26.4583241Z cert-manager has been deployed successfully!
```

However, the second command takes about 5 minutes.  Then I receive this message:

```
2018-11-08T16:28:14.4988796Z ##[error]Error: release appl-cert-manager failed: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Is this happening because the name has to be globally unique?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has the same problem, it's got a simple solution that works consistently for me.

Add a timeout argument to helm:

```
--timeout 600
```

for example for what I assume is a 10 minute timeout setting.

[image]